# Change multiple images on mouse over , with one function

Tags: javascript

I have an Exercise to querySelect the image from the HTML and change it on mouseover , I did that correctly like this :

```
var img = document.querySelector("#image1").addEventListener('mouseover' ,function (){
this.src="images/image1_2.jpg")}
```

The question is that I have an advanced exercise to change five images in the same way but with " one function "
I did it with five function this way :

```
const image1 = document.querySelector("#image1")
const image2 = document.querySelector("#image2")
const image3 = document.querySelector("#image3")
const image4 = document.querySelector("#image4")
const image5 = document.querySelector("#image5")
image1.addEventListener('mouseover', function (){
this.src = "images/image1_2.jpg"
})
image2.addEventListener('mouseover' , function (){
this.src= "images/image2_2.jpg"
})
image3.addEventListener('mouseover', function (){
this.src = "images/image3_2.jpg"
})
image4.addEventListener('mouseover', function (){
this.src = "images/image4_2.jpg"
})
image5.addEventListener('mouseover', function (){
this.src = "images/image5_2.jpg"
})
```

, but I need to do it with one function , any hint on how to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope your `img` has an initial `src`. Otherwise you won't be able to mouse over it.

That being said. You will need to use a `className` instead of an `id` for each image  because they are the same category.

```
<img src="images/image1_1.jpg" class="token" />
<img src="images/image2_1.jpg" class="token" />
<img ...
```

*Change `token` to whatever you like.*

And then select them by using either `document.getElementsByClassName` or `document.querySelectorAll`. They return an HTML collection which is an array-like object.

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll(".token");
```

In the snippets below, I use simple `div`s to illustrate what can be done.

- Using `forEach` loop. *you will have to convert the collection to an array in order to use `forEach`*

  ```js
  var imgs = [ ...document.querySelectorAll(".img") ];

  imgs.forEach((img, i) => {
    img.addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
      this.textContent = "images/image" + (i + 1) + "_2.jpg";
    });
  });
  ```

  ```css
  div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 30px;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 black;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class="img" style="background: #234;"></div>
  <div class="img" style="background: #7fb;"></div>
  <div class="img" style="background: #ace;"></div>
  <div class="img" style="background: #d8f;"></div>
  <div class="img" style="background: #e6a;"></div>
  ```
- Using a simple `for` loop. *no need for convertion*

  ```js
  var imgs = document.querySelectorAll(".img");

  for (let i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++)
    imgs[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
      this.textContent = "images/image" + (i + 1) + "_2.jpg";
    });
  ```

  ```css
  div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 30px;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 black;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class="img" style="background: #234;"></div>
  <div class="img" style="background: #7fb;"></div>
  <div class="img" style="background: #ace;"></div>
  <div class="img" style="background: #d8f;"></div>
  <div class="img" style="background: #e6a;"></div>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Don't ask us to do your exercice, but ask for a hint so you can do it by yourself and learn.

You are close to the solution. What you want is, when you hover any of the images, you want to change all the src. So your code must be something like :

When I hover any of my images (use *document.getElementsByClassName*), I've got a function which instead of changing the source of the current image changes the source of the five images (so you'll have a line by image to change each src).

Comment: Yeah got your idea , and I  totally understand , edited the question .
but I want to change every image with different image 
image 1 should be replaced with image 1_2
image 2 should be replaced with image 2_2 ... etc

Comment: Yes, you need five lines in your functions something like : img1.src = image1_2; img.src = image2_2;...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe make the event listener 'listen' on the body element, then check which element was hovered whith an if statement. I think it can be done whithout 'if' too. You will have to use 'this'.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear if you want to change ALL images with one hover or one-by-one.
If you want to change all images in same time, your function should look something like this.

```
function changeall{
      document.getElementById("image1").src="....";
      document.getElementById("image2").src="....";
      document.getElementById("image3").src="....";
      document.getElementById("image4").src="....";
      document.getElementById("image5").src="....";
}
```

If you want to change it one by one it will require your to modify your html code also.I don't want to finish your exercise therefore I will only write you main points that you need to look after

1. Make your images have same class
2. Add two functions *onmouseover* and one onmouseout
   One function should change custom attribute so that you know which image was hovered on 
   example: 
   `<img .... onmouseover="changeimg();function(){document.getElementById("id-of-that-img").customattribute ="1";}" onmouseout="document.getElementById("id-of-that-img").customattribute ="0";}">`

I know that it is kinda messy but I didn't want to create separate named functions for this.
When customattribute is at 0 you know that it is not being hovered on, and when its 1 you know that it is.

3. Make a loop for checking each element of that class if it has customattribute === 1.
   I would personally use a variable to counter for my images.
   something like this:

   var counter = 0;

   var x =setInterval(function(){

   if(document.getElementsByClassName('class')[counter].customattribute===1){

   //what_to_do_if_img_is_being_hovered_on}

   clearInterval(x);
   //stops the loop

   else{
   counter++;}},1);

I haven't tried the code out and it probably has a flaw but it is there just to give you a hint about how you can solve your problem.